# CSS - overriding transition for both to and from a certain state

Tags: css, css-transitions

Assume I have a simple button with a transition:

`<button id="myBtn" type="button">Button A</button>`

```
#myBtn {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

The above CSS I cannot touch because the transition is needed by other javascript-driven effects. But I would like to assign this button a different bg when pressed, and I would like this colour change to happen without transition. So naturally, this:

```
#myBtn {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
#myBtn:active {
  transition: background-color 0s;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But this of course only disables the transition when the button goes to the `:active` state, not when it returns from it. In other words, when the press is released, the original colour restores with a 1s transition, whereas I want it to restore immediately. So my question is, is there a way to override the transition for both to and from a particular state in CSS?

P.S.

I am aware I can do this in JS, something like:

```
btn.onmouseup(() => {
  btn.style.transition = "background-color 0s";
  setTimeout(() => btn.style.transition = "", 10);
  // Actually this doesn't even work because DOM can't react in 10ms
});
```

I'm just wondering if this can be done in a more maintainable and less ugly way (i.e. pure HTML & CSS).

Comment: How about adding a transparent overlay that becomes visible when the button goes active?

Comment: I imagine that wouldn't be any less ugly than the JS I've got here, probably more so tbh. Also it doesn't help with other properties that can be transitioned.

Comment: I completely don't understand your question, but from what I comprehend, keyframes is what you are looking for. If you explain some more maybe I can give out a working solution.

Comment: @dixitk13 I don't think keyframes is what I want - transition module's default timing functions are perfectly good for my use case. You can think up my problem as a cutoff point problem - I want a particular transition to be applied to both the rising and falling edges of a state transition, while declaring said transition in said state only covers the rising edge, not the falling edge. I am asking for a simple method to cover both, if this method exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a visual overlay that is only visible as long as the button is active:

```css
    
    #myBtn {
      transition: background 1s;
      position: relative;
    }
    #myBtn:before {
      content: "Button";
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    }
    #myBtn:active:before {
      visibility: visible;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Not sure what your metric for ugliness is, but this is pure CSS and very concise, though admittedly somewhat hacky.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While this does work for a trivial example, I don't think it will help my actual issue in production code. 1. Production code changes the button's size using JS, 2. Production code sets the text of the button dynamically. Also this is well, pretty ugly. I really don't want the maintenance nightmare that comes with code like this.

Comment: I guess by 'ugly' I just mean 'difficult to maintain'. This is a 'plaster it up' kind of solution that I (and my team leader particularly) strongly dislike.

Comment: Button size should be covered in the example above. Dynamic text needs some modifications - it shouldn't be difficult to position the text above the before element, though. Maintainability is a somewhat easier concept to understand tha ugliness.